# how do I move the error messages to the right of the text boxes while keeping the text box centered?

Tags: html, css

I'm creating a form for a new site I'm building, but cannot figure out how to display the error messages to the right of the text boxes, all while keeping the text boxes centered on the screen. So far, I've only been able to make them appear above the text boxes, but i'd rather have them show up beside them. Any help you can offer would be greatly appreciated.

Here's my code...

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Register</title>
  <style>
  body {
    background-color: silver;
  }
  .welcome {
    text-align: center;
    font-family: "Arial";
    font-size: 30px;
    text-shadow: 2px 2px lightgrey;
    color: white;
    padding-top: 15px;
  }
  .form-group {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: center;
    text-align: center;
  }
  input[name=username], input[name=first_name], input[name=last_name], input[name=email],
  input[name=password], input[name=confirm_password] {
    border: 3px solid lightgrey;
    padding: 10px;
    background: white;
    margin: 0 0 10px 0;
    width: 250px;
    outline:0 !important;
  }
  .help-block {
    font-family: "Arial";
    font-size: 12pt;
    color: white;
    padding-bottom: 10px;
  }
  input[type=submit] {
    color: grey;
    border: 3px solid lightgrey;
    padding: 5px;
    width: 100px;
    text-align: center;
  }
  input[type=submit]:focus {
    outline:0 !important;
  }
  input[type=submit]:hover {
    background-color: #ddd;
  }
  input[type=submit]:active {
    background-color: #aaa;
    color: lightgrey;
  }
  </style>
</head>
<div class="welcome">
  <h1>Register</h1>
</div>
<form action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]); ?>" method="post">
  <div class="form-group <?php echo (!empty($username_err)) ? 'has-error' : ''; ?>">
    <span class="help-block"><?php echo $username_err; ?></span>
    <input type="text" name="username" class="form-control" value="<?php echo $username; ?>" placeholder="Username">
  </div>
  <div class="form-group <?php echo (!empty($first_name_err)) ? 'has-error' : ''; ?>">
    <span class="help-block"><?php echo $first_name_err; ?></span>
    <input type="text" name="first_name" class="form-control" value="<?php echo $first_name; ?>" placeholder="First Name">
  </div>
  <div class="form-group <?php echo (!empty($last_name_err)) ? 'has-error' : ''; ?>">
    <span class="help-block"><?php echo $last_name_err; ?></span>
    <input type="text" name="last_name" class="form-control" value="<?php echo $last_name; ?>" placeholder="Last Name">
  </div>
  <div class="form-group <?php echo (!empty($email_err)) ? 'has-error' : ''; ?>">
    <span class="help-block"><?php echo $email_err; ?></span>
    <input type="text" name="email" class="form-control" value="<?php echo $email; ?>" placeholder="Email">
  </div>
  <div class="form-group <?php echo (!empty($password_err)) ? 'has-error' : ''; ?>">
    <span class="help-block"><?php echo $password_err; ?></span>
    <input type="password" name="password" class="form-control" value="<?php echo $password; ?>" placeholder="Password">
  </div>
  <div class="form-group <?php echo (!empty($confirm_password_err)) ? 'has-error' : ''; ?>">
    <span class="help-block"><?php echo $confirm_password_err; ?></span>
    <input type="password" name="confirm_password" class="form-control" value="<?php echo $confirm_password; ?>" placeholder="Confirm Password">
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Submit">
  </div>
</form>
</html>
```

Comment: What does it have to do with `mysql`? Try not to add unnecessary tags.

Answer (score 0):

Try this solution

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Register</title>
  <style>
  body {
    background-color: silver;
  }
  .welcome {
    text-align: center;
    font-family: "Arial";
    font-size: 30px;
    text-shadow: 2px 2px lightgrey;
    color: white;
    padding-top: 15px;
  }
  form{                               /* added this */
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: center;
    text-align: center;
  }


  .form-group {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;             /* change flex-direction to row */
    align-items: center;
    text-align: center;
  }
  input[name=username], input[name=first_name], input[name=last_name], input[name=email],
  input[name=password], input[name=confirm_password] {
    border: 3px solid lightgrey;
    padding: 10px;
    background: white;
    margin: 0 0 10px 0;
    width: 250px;
    outline:0 !important;
  }
  .help-block {
    font-family: "Arial";
    font-size: 12pt;
    color: white;
    padding-bottom: 10px;
  }
  input[type=submit] {
    color: grey;
    border: 3px solid lightgrey;
    padding: 5px;
    width: 100px;
    text-align: center;
  }
  input[type=submit]:focus {
    outline:0 !important;
  }
  input[type=submit]:hover {
    background-color: #ddd;
  }
  input[type=submit]:active {
    background-color: #aaa;
    color: lightgrey;
  }
  </style>
</head>
<div class="welcome">
  <h1>Register</h1>
</div>
<form action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]); ?>" method="post">
  <div class="form-group <?php echo (!empty($username_err)) ? 'has-error' : ''; ?>">
    <span class="help-block"><?php echo $username_err; ?></span>
    <input type="text" name="username" class="form-control" value="<?php echo $username; ?>" placeholder="Username">
  </div>
  <div class="form-group <?php echo (!empty($first_name_err)) ? 'has-error' : ''; ?>">
    <span class="help-block"><?php echo $first_name_err; ?></span>
    <input type="text" name="first_name" class="form-control" value="<?php echo $first_name; ?>" placeholder="First Name">
  </div>
  <div class="form-group <?php echo (!empty($last_name_err)) ? 'has-error' : ''; ?>">
    <span class="help-block"><?php echo $last_name_err; ?></span>
    <input type="text" name="last_name" class="form-control" value="<?php echo $last_name; ?>" placeholder="Last Name">
  </div>
  <div class="form-group <?php echo (!empty($email_err)) ? 'has-error' : ''; ?>">
    <input type="text" name="email" class="form-control" value="<?php echo $email; ?>" placeholder="Email">
    <span class="help-block">Error Message</span>
  </div>

  <div class="form-group <?php echo (!empty($email_err)) ? 'has-error' : ''; ?>">
    <input type="text" name="email" class="form-control" value="<?php echo $email; ?>" placeholder="Email">
    <span class="help-block">Error Message</span>
  </div>

  <div class="form-group <?php echo (!empty($password_err)) ? 'has-error' : ''; ?>">
    <span class="help-block"><?php echo $password_err; ?></span>
    <input type="password" name="password" class="form-control" value="<?php echo $password; ?>" placeholder="Password">
  </div>
  <div class="form-group <?php echo (!empty($confirm_password_err)) ? 'has-error' : ''; ?>">
    <span class="help-block"><?php echo $confirm_password_err; ?></span>
    <input type="password" name="confirm_password" class="form-control" value="<?php echo $confirm_password; ?>" placeholder="Confirm Password">
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Submit">
  </div>
</form>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks, it sort of worked. The errors are now showing up next to the boxes, but the boxes aren't aligned in the center of the screen.

Comment: They are just hide the span element i.e the error box then display it when an error occurs

Comment: How do you do that?